# SQL Server 2008 R2 connectionstring

Tags: sql-server-2008, connection-string, global.asa

global.asa

```
Application("Connection_ConnectionString")   = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=O2JAMTRADE;User ID=USERNAME;PWD=PWD"

Application("m_Connection_ConnectionString")   = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=O2JAMTRADE;User ID=USERNAME;PWD=PWD"

Application("c_Connection_ConnectionString")   = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=O2JAM;User ID=USERNAME;PWD=PWD"

Application("Connection_ConnectionTimeout") = 80
Application("Connection_CommandTimeout") = 80
```

This is my problem:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80004005'
>
> [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.
>
> /payment/payment_input_01.asp, line 40

And this is line 40:

```
Conn.Open(Application("Connection_ConnectionString"))
```

Please help.

Comment: The Data Source should be the SQL server name.

Comment: thank you very much